# Error during Cross compiling nginx for raspberry pi

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

While trying to cross-compile nginx for raspberry pi, I am getting error during configure step itself.
My config options for cross-compile are,

*./configure --build=x86_64-linux --host=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr  --exec_prefix=/usr  --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/lib/ws --datadir=/usr/share --sysconfdir=/etc --sharedstatedir=/com --localstatedir=/var --libdir=/usr/lib --includedir=/usr/include --oldincludedir=/usr/include --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --disable-silent-rules --disable-dependency-tracking --with-libtool-sysroot=~/Documents/raspberrypi/poky/raspberryPiBuild/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi --enable-nls*

The following error is printed upon issuing this command,**./configure: error: invalid option "--build=x86_64-linux"**

Whats the mistake am doing during this step?

Comment: You don't need to specify `--build`.

Comment: Since --host is specified, it says --build is mandatory if i remove

Comment: Specify only `--host`, i.e. without `--build` and `--target`. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234959/cross-compiling-for-arm-with-autoconf).

Comment: What embedded distro are you using? Yocto? I see **poko** in your toolchain.

Comment: i am using yocto.. For BSP i am using from https://github.com/djwillis/meta-raspberrypi.

Comment: I have added a new meta-layer for adding my packages and nginx is in that layer. When it does do_configure() task, its showing that error

Comment: Are you trying to add nginx recipe yourself or are you using the existing [one](https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5032)? Does removing both build and target options help?

Comment: My yocto recipe for configuring and making nginx is very simple as below.. I haven't tried the official recipe yet...I will try and check...                                                  DESCRIPTION = "Web-server"
SECTION = "package"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
PR = "r0"
SRC_URI = "file://nginx/"
inherit autotools gettext

Comment: Thanks yegorich :) I am able to cross compile nginx with that recipe!!Thanks a lot again!!

Comment: I've posted an official answer, so that others can find it. I'll have to add nginx to Buildroot someday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yocto** project already provides a recipe for **nginx**, so you don't need to create your own recipe. See this [issue](https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5032) for more information.