# C HTTP Requests on Embedded System

Tags: c, http, cross-compiling, libcurl, embedded-linux

I'm working on writing a C program for the [Moxa UC-7110](http://www.moxa.com/product/UC-7112_UC-7110.htm) which runs uCLinux. I have installed the arm-elf-gcc tool chain provided by Moxa, and I'm able to build applications fine so far.

The problem is, I'm somewhat of a novice at C programming and the CMake system. I want to be able to make HTTP GET & POST requests, but the system I'm building for doesn't have libcurl or any similar library. I don't want to write my own, so I'd like to build libcurl or some equivalent for the Moxa, but I don't understand how to get libcurl configured for the cross compiler.

I've downloaded the libcurl source and run:

```
./configure CC=arm-elf-gcc
```

but it just fails with:

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Are the basics for cross compiling that I should be aware of? Is there a way to run `configure` with it knowing I'm cross compiling?

**EDIT**

I've started running

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-elf2flt" ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=arm-elf
```

Which should cross compile properly according to the [autoconf docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Hosts-and-Cross_002dCompilation.html), but it doesn't go into cross compilation mode, and keeps trying to execute the binaries it builds.

```
checking for arm-elf-gcc... arm-elf-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/mcantrell/curl-7.37.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Comment: You don't want to change `CC`, but rather something like `ARCH`. Search around, there's plenty of information on cross compiling out there.

Comment: So if I just pass `ARCH=ARM9` that should cover it?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234959/cross-compiling-for-arm-with-autoconf

Comment: @harmic That post is helpful, but doesn't provide enough to fix my problem. I've updated my question with more information, and I'm now providing build and host args to autoconf, but it's still trying to build and test binaries, suggesting autoconf isn't in cross compile mode for some reason.

Comment: The option is something like `--target=` or `--host=`. Try `./configure --help` and look for cross-compilation options.

Comment: This is covered in the docs/INSTALL in the curl source tree. Follow that and if that doesn't work, tell us exactly what you did and what didn't work.

Comment: In particular, [CROSS COMPILE section](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/docs/INSTALL#L878) of *docs/INSTALL*.  The option `--with-random=/dev/urandom`, maybe useful with version **7.22** and maybe other versions.  You need libraries compiled for the ARM, that libcurl may depend on, such as OpenSSL if you are using `--with-ssl`.