# cross compiling with autoconf

Tags: c, cross-compiling, autoconf

I was trying to cross compile with autoconf.
I had tried from these helps :

1. https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Hosts-and-Cross_002dCompilation.html
2. https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html
3. https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/274
4. [Cross Compiling For ARM With Autoconf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234959/cross-compiling-for-arm-with-autoconf)

And did -

```
./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf --disable-shared --disable-documentation
```

But after autoconf tool checking for the gcc and other things necessary for compilation it doesn't find these. Although they are already present in the directory.

So the log is :

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for /opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for /opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for /opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar... no
checking for /opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-lib... no
checking for /opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-link... no
checking for ar... ar
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf': machine `/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub /opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf failed
```

This is the directory for all arm toolchain bin

```
host@ubuntu:/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin$ ls
arm-linux-gnueabihf-addr2line  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc         arm-linux-gnueabihf-gfortran  arm-linux-gnueabihf-readelf
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar         arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-5.4.1   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gprof     arm-linux-gnueabihf-size
arm-linux-gnueabihf-as         arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar      arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld        arm-linux-gnueabihf-strings
arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++        arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-nm      arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd    arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip
arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++filt    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib  arm-linux-gnueabihf-nm        gdbserver
arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp        arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov        arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy   runtest
arm-linux-gnueabihf-elfedit    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov-tool   arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++        arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb         arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib
```

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**
I tried the solution suggested by Chrono. It was able to find arm toolchain. But another problem arised :

error adding symbols: File format not recognized

```
libtool: link: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-address.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-async.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-block.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-coap_dtls.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-coap_event.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-coap_keystore.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-coap_time.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-debug.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-encode.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-hashkey.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-mem.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-net.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-option.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-pdu.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-resource.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-str.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-subscribe.o src/.libs/libcoap_1_la-uri.o src/platform/posix/.libs/libcoap_1_la-coap_io.o src/platform/posix/.libs/libcoap_1_la-prng.o src/platform/posix/.libs/libcoap_1_la-run.o   -L./ext/tinydtls -ltinydtls  -g -O2 -Wl,--version-script=./libcoap-1.map   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libcoap-1.so.0 -o .libs/libcoap-1.so.0.0.0
```

For this line of compilation the error is :

```
./ext/tinydtls/libtinydtls.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
```

**EDIT 2:**

The problem was with the library it is not passing the cross compiler params to the autoconf properly, hence the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-compiling for ARM with Autoconf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15234959/608639).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure the directory containing your toolchain's binaries is in your `$PATH`:

```
export OLDPATH=$PATH
export PATH=$OLDPATH:/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.01-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin
```

You should only need to do that once, unless you log out or otherwise exit that terminal session.

With that done, you can configure properly:

```
./configure \
    --build=x86_64-linux-gnu \
    --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf \
    --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf \
    --disable-shared \
    --disable-documentation
```

Comment: It was able to find the crosscompile toolchains but another error came : error adding symbols: File format not recognized. Please see the edit

Comment: The library I am compiling has another library inside . Through autoconf of the parent library , the child library autoconf is also being done. But in that case it is not taking arm crosstool from autocong. it is compiling with cc, not arm gcc.

Comment: @ninja.stop That's something that would be better explored in a different question because additional details are needed (maybe it's a known issue with the library you're compiling?), but [this mailing list thread](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tinydtls-dev/msg00061.html) might be a good start.

Comment: True. It is a problem of that library indeed. Mailed them. As per the authors it is patched. let's see. BTW, thanks for the help :)